# Replace characters suing VB script

Tags: vbscript

I want to replace a particular value followed by TRN* to some other value.How to do the coding for the same?..Please provide an example.

For **example :**

> TRN*12345*34444~

This is a segment in my file(like this I have many TRN* segments in my file).I want to replace the segment after TRN* and before next * (ie.12345)with some other value.

Is there any way to do this by using `vbscript`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to replace just this one occurrence or every occurrence of `TRN*12345*`?

Comment: I want to replace every occurrence in the file

Comment: I want to replace every occurrence in the file and one more thing is only TRN* is common for all occurrences..Remaining all things may vary across the occurences

Comment: So, if you want to replace the first number in all occurrences of `TRN*...`, what do you want to replace it with?

Comment: A common number say 12345 for example I would like to replace in all the occurrences of TRN*..But as per your example I could not hardcode the original string in code itself.The code should iterate through the file line by line and find the TRN* occurrences and replace it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, may have to tweak, can't test it at the moment

```
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "TRN\*.*?\*"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
replStr = "TRN*" & SomeOtherValue& "*"
ReplaceTest = regEx.Replace(YourStringHere, replStr)
```

Edit:

if you are looking to replace a specific number with another, a simple:

```
YourStringHere = Replace(YourStringHere,"TRN*12345*","TRN*67890*")
```

Is enough

Comment: That would replace the first occurrence of `TRN*...` whatever the value. The OP wants to replace a particular value. Also, I wouldn't recommend using `IgnoreCase` here.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression way of safetyOtter is the way to go, you only have to fiddle with the pattern and replacement string:

```
originalString = "TRN*12345*34444~"
replaceValue = "78910"

Set re = new RegExp
re.Pattern = "(.*TRN\*)([^*]+)(.*)"
re.IgnoreCase = False

' This keeps the first and last part between parenthesis, but replaces the middle part
newString = re.Replace(originalString, "$1" & replaceValue & "$3")

msgbox newString
' result: TRN*78910*34444~
```